# Finding $a,b\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $A\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ is singular and the algebraic multiplicity of its eigenvalues is $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

> Find the parameters $a,b\in\mathbb R$ for the singular matrix:
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&a&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&b&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ if the algebraic multiplicity $l_i$ of its eigenvalues is $2$.

My attempt:
Since $A\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ is singular, $\det A=0$ and therefore $k_A(0)=0$
If we observe $1^{\text{st}}\;\&\;2^{\text{nd}}$ column, $a=-1,b=-1\implies\;\det A=0$.
However, looking at $2^{\text{nd}}\;\&\;4^{\text{th}}$ row, $b=-1\implies\det A=0$.

I checked if $a=-1,b=-1$ really is the solution.

$A{\sim}J$ where $J\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ is a Jordan matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\\1&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\sim J=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A\sim J\implies k_A(\lambda)=k_J(\lambda)$$

Knowing,$$\deg k_A(\lambda)=4,\;k_A(\lambda)=\sum_{i=0}^4\alpha_i\lambda^i,$$
$$\;\alpha_4=(-1)^4=1,\;\alpha_3=(-1)^3\operatorname{trace}(A)=-2,\alpha_0=0$$
$$\&$$
$$k_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda_0)^2(\lambda-0)^2=\lambda^4-2\lambda_0\lambda^3+\lambda^2\lambda_0^2$$
$$\implies\lambda_0=1$$
Eigenvalues $0,1$ coincide with the Jordan matrix, so $(a,b)=(-1,-1)$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $k_A(0)$?  If $k_A$ is geometric multiplicity then $k_A(0) = 0$ is incorrect, assuming $A$ is singular.

Comment: It is unclear what $J$ is supposed to mean

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I apologise, I should've searched for the international notation for the characteriatic polynomial.

Comment: That's fine.  Instead of searching for notation, I'd recommend just stating that it is the characteristic polynomial

Comment: Also in my second comment I meant to say it is unclear what $A \sim J$ is supposed to mean

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I see my omission, thank you for the remark! I wanted to state that, since similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial, then the Jordan matrix I named $J$ haa the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: If $\sim$ is supposed to stand for similarity of matrices, then the statement
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\\1&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is incorrect, as is the sequence of supposed similarities afterwards

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I see, I've mistaken equivalent for similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in the second sentence, saying that $a=b=-1$ implies $\det A=0$. But the converse is not true; $\det A=0$ does not imply $a=b=-1$. This is where you go wrong.

Further, when you plug in $a=b=-1$ you get the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\end{bmatrix},$$
where the second and fourth row are equal. You correctly find that the rank of this matrix equals $3$. In particular its eigenvalue $0$ does not have multiplicity $2$, so $a=b=-1$ is not a solution.

---

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by
$$\det(xI-A)=\left|\begin{matrix}
x-1&-a&-1&0\\
-1&x+1&0&-1\\
0&0&x-1&0\\
-1&-b&0&x-1
\end{matrix}\right|
=(x-1)\left|\begin{matrix}
x-1&-a&0\\
-1&x+1&-1\\
-1&-b&x-1
\end{matrix}\right|.$$
This shows that $1$ is an eigenvalue, and because $A$ is singular $0$ is an eigenvalue. Both are required to have multiplicity $2$, so we get
$$(x-1)x^2=\left|\begin{matrix}
x-1&-a&0\\
-1&x+1&-1\\
-1&-b&x-1
\end{matrix}\right|=x^3-x^2-(a+b+1)x+b+1.$$
This shows that $b=-1$ and $a=0$.

Comment: We could also find this determinant using the formula
$$
\det\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D} = \det(AD - BC)
$$
which is [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices).

Comment: If we require that both eigenvalues have algebraic multiplicity 2 and that 0 is an eigenvalue, we can read directly from the trace that the other eigenvalue must be 1. Even more simply, the third row of $A$ tells us that $1$ is an eigenvalue.